# Protein to calorie ratio of beans and pulses vs meat and fish?

Tags: nutrition, protein, vegetarian

I do some weight lifting so I would like to have a fairly high protein diet. However id also like to eat a bit less meat, fish and eggs.

I know that nuts, seeds, beans and pulses are the best non-animal sources of protein, but how they compare per calorie?

EG if you had 100 calories of chicken and 100 calories of lentils, how much less protein would the lentils contain?

From googeling this I can find lots of resources that tell you how much protein foods have per weight, but this isnt useful for me. Lentils weigh less than chicken but I would eat a larger portion.

Comment: Questions on Nutrition are off topic here. You could commit to  the [Nutrition](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/44550/nutrition?referrer=60gsuPikc4OEtIT3irFQMg2) proposal on Area51, however.

Comment: If you really need to know, you could do the math yourself. Take `protein/g` and `kcal/g`, get rid of `1/g`, voila: `protein/kcal`.

Comment: 100 grams of chicken = 25g protein (219 calories). Same weight, 100 grams lentils = 26g protein (353 calories). However, you also have to look at complete proteins and bioavailablity.

Answer (score -1):

I know calculating sounds like the right way to approach your question but theory is theory, de facto things are often different.

I don't remember reading about any bodybuilder who promotes beans and lentils over meat. I have heard many times that beans and lentils are very high in protein but nothing replaces meat. Proteins from beans and proteins from meat just feel different. In my case my workouts are mainly strength based and whenever I cut on the meat I drop in strength(obviously trying to replace it with beans and lentils).

In the end my advice for you is to experiment and see how you feel about them. You can always go back to meat. This sounds like the only proper way to answer your question. Everybody is different and no survey can give you an ultimate answer.

Comment: I can list you plenty of vegan athletes, some of them even holding WR.

Plus your answer is anecdotal ( you dropping strenght if you cut on meat ) and intellectually dishonest.